# I need to access JSON data from outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I called, but I couldn't find it. I have a javascript file. And I have a file named data.json separate from this file.

---

**data.json**

```
{
  "today": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Note 1",
      "date": "21.05.2019",
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, optio, odit, omnis veritatis illum quo doloribus hic inventore vitae adipisci dolorem ducimus natus nostrum recusandae quis assumenda! Vel, reiciendis ipsam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, optio, odit, omnis veritatis illum quo doloribus hic inventore vitae adipisci dolorem ducimus natus nostrum recusandae quis assumenda! Vel, reiciendis ipsam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, optio, odit, omnis veritatis illum quo doloribus hic inventore vitae adipisci dolorem ducimus natus nostrum recusandae quis assumenda! Vel, reiciendis ipsam."
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to access the data inside the data.json file. But it has to work out of function.

**Example:**

**main.js**

```
let readingTab = document.createElement("div");
readingTab.innerHTML = // json
```

Comment: you can use `fetch('url/to/data.json')` to get the data from data.json

Comment: Can you specify what 'it has to work out of function' means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ES7's [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) with [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get the data from your `data.json` file like so:

```
const getData = async url => { // declare as async so we can use await
  const response = await fetch(url); // get response
  if(!response.ok) // check if response "worked" (no 404 errors etc...)
    throw Error("HTTP Error: " +response.status);

  const result = await response.json(); // get JSON from the response
  const readingTab = document.createElement("div");
  readingTab.textContent = result.today[0].text; // add text to div from retrieved JSON

}
getData('path/to/data.json');
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `readingTab.textContent = result.today[0].text` for that json? or if you want to show the entire json `readingTab.textContent = await response.text();`?

Comment: @Thomas oh yeah, my bad! Thanks Thomas :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP request to get JSON file. The data.json file path should be the same from the file where this code is written.

```
dataLoader.then(data=> {

});

export const dataLoader = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = 'GET',
    url = 'data.json';
    xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
      }
    };
  xmlhttp.send();
});
```

Comment: It's in angular. you can implement the same according to language.

Comment: so you're wrapping an XHR request in a Promise. Then why don't you use `fetch()`? *"It's in angular. you can implement the same according to language."* I'm not sure what angular has to do with this, or the question, but if you write code for angular, why don't you use `$http` or the `HttpClientModule`? XHR is not an invalid option, but the way you use it just raises questions.

Comment: @Thomas, I am using this code in the main.ts file. you can use HttpClientModule in the component. If you are using component you can use this module